# Can you write in AngularJS without any sort of preinstallation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

About a month ago, I broke my computer out of stupidity. Today, I was given a computer from my aunt-the downside, it's pretty old and doesn't take WiFi as an internet input (only ethernet). So, I decided I'd just take what I was given, and use good ol Notepad and Edge to create a webpage using Angular. Now, I am by no means an expert in this stuff, I just wanted to experiment with what I could. That is, until I can get the Ethernet set up.

Because of my incapability to use WiFi, I can't install the library/framework through Npm in the Cmd (and I presume I can't script src a link for the same reason). However, I see that Angular is "100% JavaScript" so I thought that there might be a way to do so.

TL;DR ~ Can I still write in AngularJS without WiFi?

Comment: If you have mobile internet, you could try tethering the computer via USB.  That should give you enough bandwidth to download angular libraries through NPM.

Comment: You can certainly write code without an internet connection :) - literally all in notepad if need be... But this isnt really the correct forum for asking this sort of question. Check out the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and how to ask then refine your post!

Comment: @wahwahwah I know that I can write code without an internet connection, but I wasn't sure if Angular was something that I could do, or even easily install; I've been using notepad. I did my research, finding nothing. Sorry if you feel that way, either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need be able to download the AngularJS or Angular libraries before you can start developing Angular applications. Until you can get internet access so that you can use NPM, you will have to ask someone to download the necessary files so you can develop with Angular. If you are new to Angular or unless there is a valid reason to start learning AngularJS(angular versions before version 2) then I would start with Angular. You will learn newer technologies such as Typescript, ES6, RXJS, etc.  If you are new to web development and/or build systems I would take a look at Angular CLI.  It will allow you to create Angular apps quickly without creating all the boiler plate code from scratch.

Comment: Alright, I'll use my brother's computer to code in it until I get it figured out. Thanks for the information on Angular CLI as well, I'll have to start using that until I learn it fully.

And, if I may ask, what's the difference between Angular and AngularJS (aside from 1.x and 2.x)?

Comment: Angular which is any version after 2x is completely different from 1.x.  It has typescript built in which means you will have to type your variables(string,number,boolean,etc). The cool thing about that is that it will not build if there is an error so it makes it easier to build apps without runtime errors. You also get access to ES6 classes, interfaces, and rxjs which uses observables. You can merge api requests together easily without having to deal with nested call backs or promise chains. I would start with looking around the angular docs. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You should be able to start up a localhost with something like NodeJS, MAMP, or some other server language.

If you can not create an http connection with a localhost, it shouldn't work as most modern browser sandboxing will prevent your JS scripts from being able to load.

Comment: I can't use any server language though, because using a server would require an internet connection. My entire problem is just that: I can't install the libraries without npm, and I can't install npm without an internet connection

Comment: That's not true. You can run a server locally on your machine without the need for the internet. You just need the software to be already installed on your computer. If you are able to get the angular library on your laptop, you should be able to get the node installer or MAMP to start a localhost on your computer.